# How to retrieve the Item picture details in ebay seller account through "GetMyeBaySelling" API?

Tags: python, angular, ebay-api

I tried using that api and this is the input style of json

```
{
"marketPlaceId": "",
"siteId": 3,
"api": "GetMyeBaySelling",
"fields": {
    "ActiveList": {
        "ListingType": "FixedPriceItem",
        "Include":"true",
        "IncludeNotes":"true",
        "DetailLevel":"ReturnAll",
        "Pagination": {
            "EntriesPerPage": 50,
            "PageNumber": 10
        },
    "Sort": "ItemID"
   
    }
}
```

}

I got all the details but I got the response for **"PictureDetails": null**,!! eventhough the product has pictures
why is this ?

I got all the details but I got the response for **"PictureDetails": null**,!! eventhough the product has pictures
why is this ?